# Cloudformation combining Sub ImportValue split and select functions

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create an EC2 instance and getting the SubnetID as below from ImportValue function.
The below code works perfectly well. However I want to substitute part of the ImportValue from a Parameter value that I define.

This works.

```
  MyEC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: 'ami-0611295b922472c22'  
      InstanceType: 't2.nano'
      KeyName: 'NewEC2KeyPair'
      IamInstanceProfile: 'IAMInstanceProfile'
      SubnetId: !Select [0, !Split [",", Fn::ImportValue: cfn-fy-hnz-npd-ndp-SubnetIds]]
```

However I want to substitute part of the ImportValue from a Parameter value that I define.
Such as

```
      SubnetId: !Select [0, !Split [",", Fn::ImportValue: Fn::Sub: '${TemplateName}-SubnetIds']]
```

where {TemplateName} is a parameter.

This fails as a YAML formatting issue. Please help identify what the issue is here.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: The error simply said that YAML isnt well formatted.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked

```
!Select [0, !Split [",", Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${ExportTemplateName}-SubnetIds']]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).